# How to set a number as retry condition in airflow DAG?

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

In my `Airflow DAG` i have 4 `tasks`

```
task_1 >> [task_2,task_3]>> task_4
```

`task_4` runs only after a successful run of both `task_2` and `task_3`

How do i set a condition such as :

if `task_2` fails, retry `task_2` after 2 minutes and stop retrying after the 5th attempt

This is my code :

```
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

args={
    'owner' : 'Anti',
    'start_date':days_ago(1)# 1 means yesterday
}

dag = DAG(dag_id='my_sample_dag',default_args=args,schedule_interval='15 * * * *')

def func1(**context):
    print("ran task 1")

def func2(**context):
    print("ran task 2")

def func3(**context):
    print("ran task 3")

def func4(**context):
    print("ran task 4")

with dag:
    task_1=PythonOperator(
        task_id='task1',
        python_callable=func1,
        provide_context=True,
        
    )
    task_2=PythonOperator(
        task_id='task2',
        python_callable=func2,
        provide_context=True 
    )
    task_3=PythonOperator(
        task_id='task3',
        python_callable=func3,
        provide_context=True 
    )
    task_4=PythonOperator(
        task_id='task4',
        python_callable=func4,
        provide_context=True 
    )

task_1 >> [task_2,task_3]>> task_4 # t2,t3 runs parallel right after t1 has ran
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Every operator supports `retry_delay` and `retries` - [Airflow documention](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/operators/index.html#package-contents).

> retries (int) – the number of retries that should be performed before
> failing the task
>
> retry_delay (datetime.timedelta) – delay between retries

If you want to apply this for all of your tasks, you can just edit your args dictionary:

```
args={
    'owner' : 'Anti',
    'retries': 5,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=2),
    'start_date':days_ago(1)# 1 means yesterday
}
```

If you just want to apply it to task_2 you can pass it directly to `PythonOperator` - in that case the other tasks use the default settings.

One comment on your args, it's not recommended to set a dynamic relative `start_date` but rather a fixed absolute date.